# Getting user names from a Sharepoint.files() extraction (Power Query)

Tags: sharepoint, power-query

From Sharepoint, I am able to extract a table containing filenames, file extensions, and dates...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/sharepoint-folder

However, I would like to know what user modified the filename.

I cannot find how to add this field to the query.

Comment: Have you examined the contents of the Records in the Attributes column?

Comment: When expanded it gives the size, content type, and kind. 

It seems that the user attribute is not possible:
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/How-to-Power-BI-list-Document-Property-Last-Modified-Person-Name/td-p/2085421